# trouble with rules of inference practice problems

Tags: logic, symbolic-logic, fitch

Prove the following symbolized arguments applying the appropriate rules of inference:

1)

> P ∨ Q  =
>
> M ⊃ ¬ Q
>
> M  =conjunction
>
> Therefore
>
> P

2)

> (P V Q) ∧ ¬ Q
>
> P ⊃ R =hypothetical syllogism
>
> R ⊃ S =hypothetical syllogism
>
> Therefore
>
> S

I have watched countless videos on how to do these questions and this is all I was given as to complete the questions. I'm unsure if i'm even doing it correctly if im not just finding the right rules for each line.

Comment: I am not sure what you are trying to do. Which lines are assumptions? You might try using the this proof checker to help with these problems: http://proofs.openlogicproject.org/

Comment: Review your list of rules of inference and find the suitable one to be used with M and M ⊃ ¬ Q, and so on.

Comment: So, the conclusion would be 1=p and 2=s and everything above that is assumptions. I'm unfamiliar with this concept so sorry if it's confusing.

Comment: Would this be a good first start with modus ponens?

Comment: If this is a HW question you need to explain your efforts to solve it for us to help. And regardless, please reformat it into a more readable form, and add some explanatory text.

Comment: I'm unsure what is not readable.1 stops when 2 starts

Comment: You need to explain which rules you have available (which ones you've used in class) and also explain how you've attempted to solve it. We are not here to do your homework for you, but we can help if you've shown that you've made effort yourself.

Comment: okay so I worked through the rules but am still having trouble on a few. Modus ponens
Modus tollens
hypothetical syllogism
constructive dilemma 
simplification
addition
conjunction 
demorgans law

Comment: Add what you've done and what you are using to your question under what you've written, something like "I have access to these rules: x, y, .. I attempted to solve 1 by doing a, b, and c, but now I'm stuck"

Comment: I have used the rules on hypothetical syllogism and matched them up to P ⊃ R and R ⊃ Sas well as M in part one to conjunction but I am having difficulty figuring out how to start or find the rule for M ⊃ ¬ Q and the beginning of the equations.

Comment: Am I doing this correctly and is the top of the equations just called a premise? I'm taking this class online and haven't taken a class like this before so I'm very unsure what's going on.

Comment: @DrewMcElwain  Are you sure that you have stated the problems correctly? #1- the conclusion 'P' looks incorrect. #2-the relevance of the first statement is unclear.

Comment: they are both correct unless the professor incorrectly wrote it out.

Comment: @MarkAndrews Why do you think it's incorrect? M and M ⊃ ¬Q entail ¬Q; ¬Q and P ∨ Q entail P.

Comment: @Eliran  Whoops! Misinterpreted the first premise. The reasoning in #1 is correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You appear to be asked to prove the conclusion from the premises using certain rules of inference.

I'll do you a favour and list the rules you need, but leave it to you to replace the elipsis.

```
1.|  P ∨ Q        premise
2.|  M ⊃ ¬ Q      premise
3.|_ M            premise
4.|  ...       by modus ponens ..., ...    
5.|  P            disjunctive syllogism ..., ...
```

.

```
1.|   (P V Q) ∧ ¬ Q    premise 
2.|   P ⊃ R            premise
3.|_  R ⊃ S            premise
4.|   ...           by hypothetical syllogism ..., ... 
5.|   ...              simplification ...
6.|   ...              simplification ...
7.|   ...              disjunctive syllogism ..., ...                 
8.|   S                modus ponens ..., ...
```